# USB ports, DVD drive, SD slot not mounting

Tags: usb, mount

The other day my Ubuntu 12.04 system was working fine. I could put in a flash drive and move files back and forth. I put in a CD and Ubuntu prompted me what to do. After turning on my computer and popping my flash drive in nothing happened, same with the CD.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Any error messages?